# cannot import name 'randn_tensor' from 'diffusers.utils'

Tags: python, machine-learning, huggingface, stable-diffusion

[image]

I was using this autotrain collab and when i labbelled and put my images into images folder and tried to run it , It says this error how do i solve this ?

to reproduce :

1. click link of ipynb
2. make a new folder name images
3. add some images and replace the prompt to something which describes your images
4. go to runtime and run all

[ipynb link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/autotrain-advanced/blob/main/colabs/AutoTrain_Dreambooth.ipynb)

Comment: Please do **not** post screenshots or links to code - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening due to the newer version of diffusers library.
At the very start, run `pip install diffusers==0.20.2` and then execute the cells.